# Read Binary File - Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-data

I am trying to read the contents of a binary file. I am currently able to read the file, but it cannot read the entire contents of the file, because the software returns the error in the terminal (**Segmentation fault**), what's wrong with my code?

My output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 a0 f2 41 0 0 0 0 0 88 be e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 b3 60 5f 7c 6 7f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 88 be e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a0 c4 7b 7c 2 0 0 0 80 11 40 0 0 0 0 0 d0 12 40 0 0 0 0 0 49 d2 9f 81 bc c5 24 f0 90 10 40 0 0 0 0 0 80 be e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 49 d2 df fa 6d a0 df f 49 d2 51 41 2 3d 28 e 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 88 be e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a0 be e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 90 d1 98 7c 6 7f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 90 10 40 0 0 0 0 0 80 be e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 be 10 40 0 0 0 0 0 78 be e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 1c 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 c3 dc e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 cd dc e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 d6 dc e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e6 dc e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f9 dc e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 c dd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 21 dd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 43 dd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 5c dd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 6f dd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 99 dd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f5 dd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 8 de e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 24 de e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 4c de e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 68 de e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 8b de e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a6 de e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 c3 de e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 dc de e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f3 de e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 2a df e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 43 df e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 70 df e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 81 df e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a1 df e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 c4 df e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e3 df e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 11 e0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 29 e0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 47 e0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 60 e0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 7f e0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 9a e0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 b4 e0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ce e0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 97 e1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a7 e1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 bb e1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ef e1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 18 e2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 2d e2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 46 e2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 aa e2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 c0 e2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 da e2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 7 e3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 26 e3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 58 e3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 85 e3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 99 e3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 b1 e3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 da e3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e6 e3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 6 e4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 1c e4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 2e e4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 40 e4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 65 e4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 28 e5 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 47 e5 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 58 e5 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 71 e5 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a4 e5 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 c4 e5 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e9 e5 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 19 e6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 35 e6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 54 e6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 79 e6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ac e6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 c9 e6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 fc e6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 2d e7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 44 e7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 54 e7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 68 e7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 92 e7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 9f e7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ba e7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ed e7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 b8 e8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 dc e8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f2 e8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 1d e9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 3b e9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 64 e9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 7a e9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 8d e9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 c4 e9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 eb e9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 fa e9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 1e ea e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 4a ea e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 7e ea e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 8f ea e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a0 ea e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 b2 ea e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 d2 ea e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 dc ea e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e9 ea e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 16 eb e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 32 eb e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 67 eb e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 83 eb e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 9d eb e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 bf eb e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 d1 eb e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e1 eb e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f6 eb e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 8 ec e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 2e ec e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 56 ec e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 71 ec e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 84 ec e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 9a ec e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 b0 ec e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 da ec e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f4 ec e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 1e ed e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 4e ed e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 66 ed e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 91 ed e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ab ed e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 cc ed e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e6 ed e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 7 ee e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 3f ee e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 5b ee e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 7a ee e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 8e ee e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a4 ee e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ba ee e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ce ee e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e5 ee e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ff ee e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 27 ef e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 38 ef e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f5 ef e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 32 f0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 4d f0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 5f f0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 8e f0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 bd f0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 d8 f0 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 15 f1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 2e f1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 58 f1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 70 f1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 8a f1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 96 f1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 b1 f1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 df f1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 fc f1 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 d f2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 3e f2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 4b f2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 62 f2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 8c f2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 b8 f2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f2 f2 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 21 f3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 42 f3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 5b f3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 6b f3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 7c f3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 96 f3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a1 f3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 c4 f3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 cc f3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f5 f3 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 16 f4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 40 f4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 4f f4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 8f f4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 b1 f4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 cc f4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e1 f4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f8 f4 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 12 f5 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 3a f5 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 5d f5 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 df f5 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 b f6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 45 f6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 5c f6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 75 f6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 b1 f6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 d6 f6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ef f6 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 61 f7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 72 f7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 bb f7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 d9 f7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ea f7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 3 f8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 18 f8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 33 f8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 5b f8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 77 f8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 91 f8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a5 f8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 bc f8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 d2 f8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f4 f8 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 b f9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 27 f9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 4a f9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 59 f9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 7e f9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ab f9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 cc f9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f4 f9 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e fa e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 22 fa e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 52 fb e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 89 fb e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 c1 fb e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 1b fc e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 35 fc e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 55 fc e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 79 fc e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 87 fc e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a7 fc e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 d7 fc e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 10 fd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 47 fd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 65 fd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 8e fd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a4 fd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ba fd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e4 fd e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 13 fe e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 31 fe e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 44 fe e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 6a fe e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 8b fe e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 a2 fe e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 c8 fe e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e2 fe e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 fa fe e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 36 ff e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 4a ff e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 5c ff e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 91 ff e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 ae ff e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 c4 ff e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 e2 ff e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 21 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 e0 f5 b2 fd 7f 0 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ff fb 8b 1f 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 40 0 40 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 38 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 e0 95 7c 6 7f 0 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 90 10 40 0 0 0 0 0 b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 e8 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 e8 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 d 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 e8 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 e 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 e8 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 99 c7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 1a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ee ff e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 a9 c7 e8 b2 fd 7f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: Please insert the file to recover photos\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        FILE *file;

        unsigned char buffer[10];

        file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

        long posicao = ftell(file);

        printf("Ponteiro no Inicio %ld\n", posicao);

        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

        posicao = ftell(file);

        printf("Ponteiro no Fim: %ld\n",posicao);

        //Cannot open file
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            printf("Cannot open file \n");
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            //Read the content
            fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, file);

            for(int i = 0; i < posicao; i++)
            {
                printf("%x ", buffer[i]); // prints a series of bytes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to check if `argv[1]` is valid and if `fopen` fails. Actually yo do check if `fopen` fails here: `if (file == NULL)` , but it's too late you need to check this right after `fopen`.

Comment: The `posicao` in the for-loop is possibly much larger than the buffer's size (i.e. 10)?

Comment: Yes, I know the buffer[10] is very small, but I thought about doing something like that, but I don't know if I do it right. buffer[ ] = posicao

Comment: I added what I'm getting on the terminal

Comment: Your output verifies that as Yun already mentioned in comment above, `posicao` is larger than the number of elements in `buffer`. In your loop you access the array way out of bounds causing undefined behaviour and in your case a segmentation fault.

Comment: error: expression result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-value] buffer[posicao];

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Check if the file was opened right after using `fopen` (as stated in the question comments)
2. Move the cursor to the beginning of the file after using `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);`
3. Correctly choose the fread parameters and get their return value:

- `fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file);`. Where `sizeof(buffer)` is number of elements of buffer. See comment and answer from **@chux - Reinstate Monica**. `sizeof(buffer)` does not work correctly if buffer is dynamically allocated.
- `fread(buffer, sizeof(*buffer), sizeof(buffer), file);`. Get size of first element with `sizeof(*buffer)`.
- `fread(buffer, 1, posicao, file);`. If posicao <= sizeof buffer.

4. Access buffer until to the number of bytes read.
   `for (size_t i = 0; i < readed; i++) printf("%x ", buffer[i]);`. Attention to the fread return as told by **@chux - Reinstate Monica** (returns size_t an eight byte type)

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: Please insert the file to recover photos\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        FILE *file;

        file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

        //Cannot open file --> check pointer file after fopen
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            printf("Cannot open file \n");
            exit(0);
        }

        long posicao = ftell(file);

        printf("Ponteiro no Inicio %ld\n", posicao);

        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

        posicao = ftell(file);

        rewind (file); // Sets the position indicator associated with stream to the beginning of the file

        unsigned char buffer[posição]; // o buffer deveria ser criado aqui depois de pegar a posição final

        printf("Ponteiro no Fim: %ld\n",posicao);

        // Read the content --> é sempre bom verificar o valor lido
        // o terceiro parâmetro estava 1, deveria ser a "posicao"
        size_t readed = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), posicao, file);

        for(size_t i = 0; i < readed; i++) // usar readed como limite
        {
            printf("%x ", buffer[i]); // prints a series of bytes
        }
    }
}
```

References:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/

Comment: `fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), posicao, file);` attmepts to read `posicao * posicao` bytes.  Likely returns 1 and not the hoped for `posicao`.  Return value of `fread()` may exceeed `INT_MAX`.  `unsigned char buffer[posicao]` is _undefined behavior_ when `posicao == 0`.  Some files have 0 size.

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` returns 1 (because `buffer` is a pointer to `unsigned char`), and position will be the number of bytes in the file, so `1*position` bytes will result. And the number of bits of `int` is 32 and of `size_t` is 16, so there's no way the return value of fread exceeds `INT_MAX`: `SIZE_MAX` = 65535, `INT_MAX` = 2147483647.

Comment: @CodeMaker, it's because it's `rewind(pFile)`, it should be `rewind(file)` for you.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Gean Santos, "sizeof(buffer) returns 1 (because buffer is a pointer to unsigned char)" is incorrect.  `buffer` is an array, not a pointer.  The `sizeof(buffer)` is `posicao`.  Try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(buffer));`.

Comment: Gean Santos, "number of bits of int is 32 and of size_t is 16" is not specified by C.  `int` is commonly 32-bit, could be as small as 16.  `size_t` commonly 32-bit or 64-bit, could be as small as 16.  The return value from `fread()` may exceed `INT_MAX`.  Example `printf("%d %zu\n", INT_MAX, SIZE_MAX);` --> 2147483647 18446744073709551615

Comment: You're right @chux - Reinstate Monica, `size_t` turned out to be 8 bytes long. I edited the response as requested by @Community and as per your corrections.

Comment: Suggest `fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), posicao, file)` --> `fread(buffer, 1, posicao, file)` or the like.

Comment: this statement `long posicao = ftell(file);` will return 0.  Suggest elimination of the the statement

Comment: regarding: `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

        rewind (file); // não estava voltando para o início do arquivo

        posicao = ftell(file);`   this call to `ftell()` will return 0.  suggest:  `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); posicao = ftell(file); rewind (file);`

        rewind (file); // não estava voltando para o início do arquivo

Comment: Thanks @user3629249, it has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Code attmepts to write past the end of `buffer[]`.
Do not print more than read.

```
// fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, file);
// for(int i = 0; i < posicao; i++)

size_t n = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file);
for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

---

Add error checking in the right places.

To read more than 10, allocate memory or use a variable length array  (VLA).  A VLA needs more testing to insure its size is not 0 (easy) and not too big (hard to do).

```
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)) {
        printf("Cannot fseek\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    rewind(file); // Go back to beginning

    long posicao = ftell(file);
    if (posicao == -1 || (unsigned long) posicao > SIZE_MAX) {
        printf("Trouble with ftell %ld\n", posicao);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size_t sz = (size_t) posicao;
    
    unsigned char *buffer == malloc(sz);
    if (buffer == NULL && sz > 0) {
        printf("Cannot malloc %zu\n", sz);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    printf("Size %zu\n", sz);

    size_t read_count = fread(buffer, 1, sz, file);
    if (read_count != sz) {
        printf("Size mis-match %zu %zu\n", sz, read_count);
    } 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < read_count; i++) {
        printf("%x ", buffer[i]);
    }

    free(buffer);
    fclose(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. eliminates redundant code
2. properly obtains length of file
3. properly declares the input buffer
4. properly reads the file
5. properly uses the number of bytes read from file to control loop
6. does not check for all the errors that it should

The buffer is properly sized to hold the whole file so buffer is not overflowed.  Such overflow would result in a seg fault event.

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s inputFileName\n Please insert the file to recover photos\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FILE file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    //Cannot open file
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file \n"); // better to use perror()
        exit(0);  // 0 indicates success, better to use -1
    }       

    
    // move file pointer to end of file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

    // get current file pointer location, relative to beginning of file
    long posicao = ftell(file);

    // move file pointer to start of file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET );
    
    printf("Ponteiro no Inicio %ld\n", posicao);

    // generate correct buffer size via a VLA (variable length array)
    unsigned char buffer[ posicao ];
    
    //Read the content and recover number of bytes read
    size_t bytesread = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, file);

    // use number of bytes read as index limiter to display bytes
    for( size_t i = 0; i < bytesread; i++)
    {
        printf("%x ", buffer[i]); // prints a series of bytes
    }
}
```